# Has a universality theorem been proved for the Davenport-Heilbronn L function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, l-functions

The question is in the title: has a universality theorem in the sense of Voronin been proved for the Davenport-Heilbronn function, or do we expect such a theorem to hold true only for L functions that are supposed to verify the analogue of the Riemann Hypothesis?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Davenport-Heilbronn= Hurwitz zeta with irrational $q$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://siauliaims.su.lt/pdfai/2008/laurincikas-08.pdf

> **Abstract.** In the paper, the joint universality in the Voronin sense for
>   Hurwitz zeta-functions with parameters $a_1; \dots ; a_r$ such that the system
>   $\{ \log(m + a_j) : m = 0;1;2; \dots ; j = 1; \dots ; r \}$ is linearly independent over
>   the field of rational numbers is obtained.

For irrational $q$, the requirements are true (see Corollary 2).

Interesting side remark:

> Quote: If q is algebraic irrational, then J. W. S. Cassels proved that at least 51
>   percent of elements of the set
>   $\{ log(m + q) : m \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: +1, You really are an expert on universality!

Comment: Thanks for the flowers. To be honest, this did require only googling for "universality of Hurwitz zeta" and some cross-reading though;)